# SVG path ignores anchor point

Tags: google-maps, svg

The `anchor:` of my icon is ignored although I think the "moves" are absolute and not relative. No matter what values I supply for `anchor:` in my code, the SVG markers are unchanged.  To be more specific, the pins are being positioned downward and to the right of where they should be. Is it because I am using bezier curves, or what?

```
function createMarker(point,text,ID,color,label,pinage) { 
    var stroke = "000000"
    var icon = {

path: "M16,3.5c-4.142,0-7.5,3.358-7.5,7.5c0,4.143,7.5,18.121,7.5,18.121S23.5,15.143,23.5,11C23.5,6.858,20.143,3.5,16,3.5z M16,14.584c-1.979,0-3.584-1.604-3.584-3.584S14.021,7.416,16,7.416S19.584,9.021,19.584,11S17.979,14.584,16,14.584z",
      fillColor: color,
      fillOpacity: .8,
      anchor: google.maps.Point(0.0, 0.0),
      strokeWeight: 1,
      scale:1.4
    };
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: point, map: map , title: text, icon: icon,  zIndex: ID});
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've ommitted the `new`-keyword, it has to be:

```
anchor: new google.maps.Point(0.0, 0.0),
```